# Finite difference for higher order pde in python

Tags: python, numeric, differential-equations

I have been attempting to solve some PDE equations, and while I have been able to successfully do simple ones like the diffusion or wave equation using a finite difference method, I am having difficulty doing so with higher order PDE.

For example, let's say I wish to solve the following equations

```
U_{xxxx}-x-2x*x_{tx}-2x_{xxtt}-x_{tt}=0
```

My experience so far has been only with explicit finite difference (using a central difference mainly). This is clearly not possible for a differential equation like this.

Most of the resources I can find only work up to second order derivatives, and they aren't usually coupled. In addition, there may be a more effective way than using a finite difference method to solve an equation like this.

I have mainly been playing around with a code from a textbook that uses a basic wave equation, but it can likely be trimmed or replaced completely for better usage; I am not even sure if it can entirely be used for my more complex case.

```
def solver(I, V, f, c,U_0,U_L, L, dt, C, T, user_action=None):
"""Solve u_tt=c^2*u_xx + f on (0,L)x(0,T]."""
Nt = int(round(T/dt))
t = np.linspace(0, Nt*dt, Nt+1)   # Mesh points in time
dx = dt*c/float(C)
Nx = int(round(L/dx))
x = np.linspace(0, L, Nx+1)       # Mesh points in space
C2 = C**2; dt2 = dt*dt  # Help variable in the scheme
# Make sure dx and dt are compatible with x and t
dx = x[1] - x[0]
dt = t[1] - t[0]

if f is None or f == 0 :
    f = (lambda x, t: 0)
if V is None or V == 0:
    V = (lambda x: 0)

if I is None or I == 0:
    I = (lambda x: 0)

if U_0 is not None:
    if isinstance(U_0, (float,int)) and U_0 == 0:
        U_0 = lambda t: 0
    # else: U_0(t) is a function
if U_L is not None:
    if isinstance(U_L, (float,int)) and U_L == 0:
        U_L = lambda t: 0

u     = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # Solution array at new time level
u_n   = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # Solution at 1 time level back
u_nm1 = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # Solution at 2 time levels back
Ix = range(0, Nx+1)
It = range(0, Nt+1)

import time;  t0 = time.clock()  # Measure CPU time

# Load initial condition into u_n
for i in Ix:
    u_n[i] = I(x[i])

if user_action is not None:
    user_action(u_n, x, t, 0)
# Special formula for the first step
for i in Ix[1:-1]:
    u[i] = u_n[i] - dt*V(x[i]) + \
           0.5*C2*(u_n[i-1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[i+1]) + \
           0.5*dt2*f(x[i], t[0])

i = Ix[0]
if U_0 is None:
    # Set boundary values du/dn = 0
    # x=0: i-1 -> i+1 since u[i-1]=u[i+1]
    # x=L: i+1 -> i-1 since u[i+1]=u[i-1])
    ip1 = i+1
    im1 = ip1  # i-1 -> i+1
    u[i] = u_n[i] -dt*V(x[i]) + \
           0.5*C2*(u_n[im1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[ip1]) + \
           0.5*dt2*f(x[i], t[0])
else:
    u[0] = U_0(dt)

i = Ix[-1]
if U_L is None:
    im1 = i-1
    ip1 = im1  # i+1 -> i-1
    u[i] = u_n[i] + dt*V(x[i]) + \
           0.5*C2*(u_n[im1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[ip1]) + \
           0.5*dt2*f(x[i], t[0])
else:
    u[i] = U_L(dt)

if user_action is not None:
    user_action(u, x, t, 1)

# Switch variables before next step
u_nm1, u_n, u = u_n, u, u_nm1

for n in It[1:-1]:
    # Update all inner points
    for i in Ix[1:-1]:
        u[i] = - u_nm1[i] + 2*u_n[i] + \
               C2*(u_n[i-1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[i+1]) + \
               dt2*f(x[i], t[n])

    i = Ix[0]
    if U_0 is None:
        # Set boundary values
        # x=0: i-1 -> i+1 since u[i-1]=u[i+1] when du/dn=0
        # x=L: i+1 -> i-1 since u[i+1]=u[i-1] when du/dn=0
        ip1 = i+1
        im1 = ip1
        u[i] = - u_nm1[i] + 2*u_n[i] + \
               C2*(u_n[im1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[ip1]) + \
               dt2*f(x[i], t[n])
    else:
        u[0] = U_0(t[n+1])

    i = Ix[-1]
    if U_L is None:
        im1 = i-1
        ip1 = im1
        u[i] = - u_nm1[i] + 2*u_n[i] + \
               C2*(u_n[im1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[ip1]) + \
               dt2*f(x[i], t[n])
    else:
        u[i] = U_L(t[n+1])

    if user_action is not None:
        if user_action(u, x, t, n+1):
            break

    # Update data structures for next step
    #u_nm1[:] = u_n;  u_n[:] = u  # safe, but slower
    u_nm1, u_n, u = u_n, u, u_nm1
u = u_n
cpu_time = time.clock() - t0
return u, x, t, cpu_time
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? after reading your question i have no idea what kind of feedback you want.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear. I guess I was just unsure as to how to actually start writing such a code.